# Whether an equation has a solution

Tags: number-theory

Will the following equation have a solution in $\mathbb Z$?

$n_1^2+n_2^2+n_1n_2=3$ for $n_1\neq n_2$

Comment: No $n_1=n_2=0$ is the only integer solution

Comment: Sorry it will be 3 not 0 in R.H.S

Comment: Sorry. I am hopeless. The solution to $a^2 + a x + x^2 - 3$
is an ellips through some points with a and x = 1,2,-1,-2 so I believe there are no large number solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$(1,-2)$ and $(2,-1)$ are solutions, so the answer to your question is yes.

I believe there are no other solutions (I tested for $0\le n_1 \le 50000$ and $-50000\le n_2 \le0$), but I'm still working on proving it

Comment: beg to differ. see below.

Comment: @NumThcurious: the equation is symmetric in $n_1$ and $n_2$ so i assumed as obvious that if $(n_1,n_2)$ is a solution then $(n_2,n_1)$ is also a solution. This also justifies my choice to test only for positive $n_1$ and negative $n_2$ and not vice-versa

Comment: very clever argument

Comment: @NumThcurious anyway i just bruteforced it with a computer program, so i prefer your solution over mine

Comment: I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you write:$n_1+n_2=x$ and $n_1-n_2=y$, then we can write $n_1=\frac{x+y}{2}$ and $n_2=\frac{x-y}{2}$this will yield to:$$3x^2+y^2=12$$ or$$x^2+\frac13{y^2}=4 $$ Since $3$ does not divide $1$ then it has to divide $y^2$.
Given that $y^2<4$, the only possibles solutions are $y=-3$ and $y=
+3$, which both yield to the couples $ (x,y)$: $$(-1,-3);(-1,3);(+1,-3);(+1,3)$$
Note that $y\neq0$ because by hypothesis $n_1\neq n_2$

By plugging in each of one of the above couples in the $n_1=\frac{x+y}{2}$ and $n_2=\frac{x-y}{2}$, you will obtain the following $(n_1,n_2)$ couples: $$(-2,1);(1,-2);(-1,2);(2,-1)$$

Comment: @learning maths, what do you think about about my answer to the question?